Laravel не отправляет почту smtp
Конфиг
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => env('MAIL_URL'),
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
            'username' => env('email@gmail.com'),
            'password' => env('secret'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN', 'localhost'),
        ],

Ошибка
Expected response code "250" but got code "530", with message "530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. For more information, go to 530 5.7.0 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError 38308e7fff4ca-2ffa4d3dbb1sm5242751fa.26 - gsmtp".
Пробовал всё, ничего не помогает.

Laravel Expected response code 250 but got code "530"
